# Text Formatting Not working in Admonition Blocks AsciiDoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

I am trying to do simple text formatting such as

```
[NOTE]
====
Note: This is *ONLY* an example
====
```

however, it processes the "* ONLY *" as text and not a bold text format. Same thing for "** ONLY **" as well as italics formatting etc.

I can't seem to find any documentation on whether there needs to be something specified in the document header in order to enable text formatting in admonition blocks. Any help would be great.

Comment: could you please add four spaces in front of you code-example? than stackoverflow renders it as code, you could write it as is and I could copy it as is to see where the problem is. (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Your example renders correctly for me. Where does this admonition exist? Is it in a table cell, or other block where certain kinds of substitutions might have been disabled?